# How to use RewriteRule in order to do an invisibly search query?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Before of all I want to say that I have been researching but I still have not found a solution to this problem.
I want to do an invisibly redirect. With this URL http://www.localhost.com/@user_name/search/?q=string to do a search without redirecting to another page, because I should check the user @user_name in the MySQL database in order to retrieve its user profile.

## PHP script search.php

```
<?php
    echo 'USER:'.$_GET['user'].'<br/>';
    echo 'QUERY q:'.$_GET['q'].'<br/>';
?>
```

## .htaccess

```
#Begin invisibly redirect 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

#This works with this (www.localhost.com/@user_name/search/X55)
#RewriteRule ^@([_A-Za-z0-9]+)/search/X(.*)$ /profile/search/search.php?user=$1&q=$2 [L]

#But ,for search, this doesn't work with this (www.localhost.com/@user_name/search/?q=string)
RewriteRule ^@([_A-Za-z0-9]+)/search/?q=(.*)$ /profile/search/search.php?user=$1&q=$2 [L]
#END invisibly redirect
```

## Results

## 1

With: 
   #RewriteRule ^@([_A-Za-z0-9]+)/search/X(.*)$ /profile/search/search.php?user=$1&q=$2 [L]
   AND 
   www.localhost.com/@user_name/search/X55 
 It returns 
 USER:user_name
 QUERY q:55/

## 2

With: 
   #RewriteRule ^@([_A-Za-z0-9]+)/search/?q=(.*)$ /profile/search/search.php?user=$1&q=$2 [L] 
   AND 
   www.localhost.com/@user_name/search/?q=string 
   It gives a server error.

   Help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `RewriteRule` doesn't match QUERY_STRING. It matches REQUEST_URI only. You just need `QSA` (Existing Query String Append) flag in your URL. Your rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^@(\w+)/search/?$ /profile/search/search.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I didn't know QSA, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to pass query strings:

```
RewriteRule ^@([_A-Za-z0-9]+)/search/?$ /profile/search/search.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The question mark on `..search/?$` gives the slash char `/` as optional:

```
localhost.com/@user_name/search/?q=string 
localhost.com/@user_name/search?q=string
```